# Detect faces in python with MTCNN, Opencv and multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I'm here because I'm really stuck on my project. At the beginning of my project, it was just a simple face detection that worked pretty well using Python, Opencv, and the MTCNN model. The problem was that the program was pretty slow and I tried to make it faster.  My research then, unfortunately, led me to multithreading and I didn't really know what I was getting into.

In my program, I'm using

1 **function:** `process_frame()`

2 **variables:** `frame` and `frame_buffer`

The purpose of this program is therefore to have both image processing and simultaneous playback of video streams in order to gain performance. The problem is that `imshow()` of my function `"process_frame"` works very well,  I have pictures with a face detected. However, as soon as I enter my main loop, I have a simple video stream without detection. I was just wondering if my problem would not come from a problem with the synchronization of my threads.

I know that adding multithreading can slow down my program more than anything else but you have to practice to understand ahah

I would be pleased to have a little help because I admit to being stuck for a long time

**Below is the code:**

```py
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from mtcnn import MTCNN
    import threading
    import time
    import tensorflow as tf
    from threading import Lock
    #import pdb


    #pdb.set_trace()
    lock = Lock()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    frame_buffer = []
    frame = None
    
    
    def process_frame():
        global frame_buffer, stop_event, lock, frame
        while not stop_event.is_set():
            try:
                lock.acquire()
                if frame is None:
                    print("frame vide")
                    continue
                print ("frame copié avec succes")
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (320,240))
                frame = frame_buffer
            except Exception as e:
                print("Une exception a été levée lors du traitement de l'image :", e)
                continue
            finally :
                lock.release()
            
            try:
                model = MTCNN(min_face_size=10)
                predictions = model.detect_faces(frame)
                print(f"{len(predictions)} visages détectés")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Une exception a été levée lors de la détection des visages :", e)
            
            try:
                predictions = [prediction for prediction in predictions if prediction['confidence'] > 0.5]
                print(f"{len(predictions)} visages filtrés")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Une exception a été levée lors de la filtration des prédictions :", e)
                    
            for face in predictions:
                try:
                    x, y, w, h = face['box']
                    with lock :
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
                        cv2.imwrite("parth/image_traitee_process_frame.jpg", frame_buffer,     [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100])
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Une exception a été levée lors de l'ajout de l'annotation du rectangle :", e)
            print ("frame mis a jour avec succes")
            #frame_buffer = frame
            print ("Copie de la liste de frame : ", frame, "dans frame_buffer : ", frame_buffer)
            time.sleep(0.01)

    stop_event = threading.Event()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=process_frame)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    frame_count = 0

    def stop_thread():
        stop_event.set()
        thread.join()

     
    while True:
    
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame_buffer = frame.copy()
        else :
            frame = frame_buffer
        frame = frame_buffer
        print ("valeur de frame_buffer après cap.read : ", frame_buffer)
        print (cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        print (cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        cv2.imwrite("parth/image_traitee_boucle_while.jpg", frame_buffer, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 50])
    
        if not ret:
            break
        lock.acquire()
        #frame_buffer = frame
        lock.release()
        frame_count += 1
        elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
        if elapsed_time > 1.0:
            print("Frames par seconde : ", frame_count / elapsed_time)
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            frame_count = 0
        lock.acquire()
        #print(frame_buffer.shape)
        cv2.imshow("Output", frame_buffer)
        lock.release()
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord("q"):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    stop_thread()
```

I tried a lot of things like catching some exceptions with try-except but I have nothing.
with some print statements, ret is set to true, frame in my loop got the position in `cap.read()` but I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking. From what I can read, you pass `frame_buffer` to `imshow`. The only place, where `frame_buffer` is assigned, is with the content of `cap.read`. What do you expect?

Comment: For me, the frame variable is the image captured by the video stream (ret, frame = cap.read) and framebuffer is a copy of the frame that is modified. With the processframe() function I take care of the image processing which will therefore modify frame_buffer. My goal is then to display this modified image on the screen. The problem is that the display is correct in my function but not in the loop and I don't know why.
As you can see i tried a cv2.imwrite() of frame_buffer in my function process_frame() and it's working i got a picture with the detection of my face

Comment: For me when i'm using a global variable i can call him everywhere i want. Here when the program catch a video stream (if the frame is empty the program release the lock and continue) he doing work on the frame_buffer. It's possible that I'm wrong all along the line but it's what i'm waiting for the program

Comment: Let me re-phrase my question. In your processing thread you are analyzing a picture and putting the result into `frame` (or `frame_buffer`). In your main thread you are continously capturing into `frame` and `frame_buffer`. As the main thread is running obviously much faster that your processing thread, this is overwriting the results from you processing immediately.
What do you expect to be displayed, while the background thread is running, i.e. not up-to-date result is available?